# How do I split this string in ruby to get the expected output in an array

Tags: ruby

I've this string

```
str = "Rs. 4,999Rs. 6,999Rs. 7,499Rs. 2,499Rs. 11,549Rs. 6,999Rs. 5,190Rs. 2,499Rs. 6,790Rs. 12,999Rs. 8,299Rs. 9,999Rs. 72,000Rs. 6,699Rs. 16,000Rs. 6,999Rs. 7,999Rs. 2,590Rs. 5,599Rs. 18,799"
```

How do I split this string to get my expected output in an array?

***Expected output:***

```
["Rs. 4,999", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,499", "Rs. 2,499", "Rs. 11,549", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 5,190", "Rs. 2,499", "Rs. 6,790", "Rs. 12,999", "Rs. 8,299", "Rs. 9,999" "Rs. 72,000", "Rs. 6,699", "Rs. 16,000", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,999", "Rs. 2,590", "Rs. 5,599", "Rs. 18,799"]
```

Below are my failed attempts

***#1 with scan***

```
str.scan(/.{1,9}/)

=> ["Rs. 4,999", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,499", "Rs. 2,499", "Rs. 11,54", "9Rs. 6,99", "9Rs. 5,19", "0Rs. 2,49", "9Rs. 6,79", "0Rs. 12,9", "99Rs. 8,2", "99Rs. 9,9", "99Rs. 72,", "000Rs. 6,", "699Rs. 16", ",000Rs. 6", ",999Rs. 7", ",999Rs. 2", ",590Rs. 5", ",599Rs. 1", "8,799"]
```

***#2 with split***

```
str.split(/Rs./).reject(&:empty?)
=> [" 4,999", " 6,999", " 7,499", " 2,499", " 11,549", " 6,999", " 5,190", " 2,499", " 6,790", " 12,999", " 8,299", " 9,999", " 72,000", " 6,699", " 16,000", " 6,999", " 7,999", " 2,590", " 5,599", " 18,799"]
```

I'm using *ruby 2.2.3p173*. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Comment: Where does such a string come from?

Comment: @Stefan From a nokogiri parser.

Comment: You should fix the parser to return structured data instead of a joined string.

Comment: @Stefan I'm very new to nokogiri. Do you know where can fix it?

Comment: Sure: parser.rb, line 192 ... seriously? Show your code! :-D

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968), where you're asking about Y but should have asked about X. The way you're extracting the data via Nokogiri is probably at fault, and from the string it looks like you're using `text` on a NodeSet. So the question should be how to correctly to that part, because when it's done right the resulting text will be separated into individual array elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `scan` attempt was the right way to go, but your data is incredibly regular. Instead of trying to match "1 to 9 of anything", match the literal parts and use a simple `\d` for the parts that are actually *variable* (the digits):

```
str.scan /Rs\. \d+,\d+/
=> ["Rs. 4,999", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,499", "Rs. 2,499", "Rs. 11,549", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 5,190", "Rs. 2,499", "Rs. 6,790", "Rs. 12,999", "Rs. 8,299", "Rs. 9,999", "Rs. 72,000", "Rs. 6,699", "Rs. 16,000", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,999", "Rs. 2,590", "Rs. 5,599", "Rs. 18,799"]
```

Comment: Or `str.scan(/Rs\. \d*\,?\d*/)` if you dont have `,` in number

Comment: @Pavan Note I replaced the first `\d` with a `\d+`. I didn't notice at first that some entries had two digits before the `,`.

Comment: You can also use a character class to match consecutive digits and commas: `/Rs\. [\d,]+/`

Answer (score 4):

I have assumed that the alphabetic portion of the string can vary.

```
r = /
    (?<=\d)         # match a digit in a positive lookbehind
    (?=[[:alpha:]]) # match a letter in a positive lookahead
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.split r
  #=> ["Rs. 4,999", "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,499",  "Rs. 2,499", "Rs. 11,549",
  #    "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 5,190", "Rs. 2,499",  "Rs. 6,790", "Rs. 12,999",
  #    "Rs. 8,299", "Rs. 9,999", "Rs. 72,000", "Rs. 6,699", "Rs. 16,000",
  #    "Rs. 6,999", "Rs. 7,999", "Rs. 2,590",  "Rs. 5,599", "Rs. 18,799"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a strong odor about the string you're parsing, and, combined with the fact that you're using Nokogiri to generate it, I suspect you didn't use Nokogiri correctly.

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>Rs. 4,999</td><td>Rs. 6,999</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('tr').text # => "Rs. 4,999Rs. 6,999"
```

Using `text` on a container node will cause the text of the child nodes to be concatenated. This is very rarely what you want because you end up with a string that's hard to tear apart.

Instead, find the containing node and iterate over the child nodes extracting their text:

```
doc.at('tr').search('td').map(&:text) # => ["Rs. 4,999", "Rs. 6,999"]
```

Or simply iterate over the nodes containing the text if that's safe:

```
doc.search('td').map(&:text) # => ["Rs. 4,999", "Rs. 6,999"]
```

Sometimes that results in a lot of unwanted data too, so be careful going down that path.

Answer (score -2):

This should work for your case:

```
str.split("Rs. ").select {|value| !value.empty?}
```

Comment: This is already covered and rejected in the question. It is exactly what his second example does. `select(!empty)` and `reject(empty)` *the same thing*. And anyways, the `"Rs."` part is supposed to appear in the output.